# What is the difference between the areas where you can declare instance variables in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting comfortable with iOS and Objective-C programming, but where instance variables are declared is still a confusing point for me.

- Most of the time they seem to be declared in the class' .h file, as part of the interface.
- Other times, they are declared in the .m file's interface.
- Another way I've seen is when they're declared in the .h file, but in a "separate division" of the interface, for lack of a better term, like so:

  ```
  @interface MapViewController : UIViewController {

      UIPopoverController *popoverController;

  }

  ....
  ```

Where is the correct way to put them? Is it entirely subjective? I've got the impression that for instance variables that other classes will need to access, put them as a main property in the .h file, but for variables that only the class needs to access class-wide, put them in the .m's interface. Then the special division of .h confuses me all together.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: I have to admit: Nobody's asked this question before, but it's probably because you should read [the docs on ObjC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/).  (AAAnd, queue 10 answers that are either very short or very long but don't quite answer the question below)

Comment: @CodaFi I thought Rob Napier's answer addressed this question. Although I can see how the mapping isn't 100%. If it gets closed and Doug isn't satisfied with the answers from the possible dupe I'll keep an eye on it and make sure to vote to re-open. Thanks for causing me to take a second look.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I see no reason why your dupe and the docs shouldn't constitute a dupe of the question.  I certainly voted to close (because I honestly tried this question's title ten times and couldn't come up with anything that close).